# datetime strptime(), how to get format table

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

In the docs of the [strftime() and strptime() behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) laid out list of format codes. How does datetime store it? Can i get access to it?

I mean, when i use strptime(date_string, format), its somehow handle 'format' string, so, it has to know how to associate, say, '%d' to a range of integers '01, 02, …, 31' as it described in docs. So, how does it store those associations and can i get access to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the strftime(3) documentation.

On Linux and macOS, you can run `man strftime` to see the supported format codes.

The documentation includes a table of [standard format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> The following is a list of all the format codes that the C standard (1989 version) requires, and these work on all platforms with a standard C implementation. Note that the 1999 version of the C standard added additional format codes.

**Update**

In response to your comment below, the format codes are part of the C library for the platform. I know of no way to access them from Python.